# Custom RTTI for use in script-defined types

Tags: c++, python, rtti, boost-python

I'm developing a game engine in C++ that allows Python scripting. Here's an example of how functions can be defined in Python that are then called by the an event manager whenever a certain event occurs:

```
# Import some classes defined in C++
from cpp.event import PlayerDiesEvent, EventManager

def onPlayerDeath(event):
    pass

em = EventManager()
em.connect(PlayerDiesEvent, onPlayerDeath)
em.post(PlayerDiesEvent(...)) # Will call `onPlayerDeath`
```

The user can also define new types of events:

```
from cpp.event import Event, EventManager

class CustomEvent(Event):
    pass

def onCustomEvent(event):
    pass

em = EventManager()
em.connect(CustomEvent, onCustomEvent)
em.post(CustomEvent())
```

However, I would also like the messaging system to work with inheritance, which it currently does not. Here's what I mean:

```
from cpp.event import PlayerDiesEvent, EventManager

class CustomEvent(PlayerDiesEvent):
    pass

def onPlayerDeath(event):
    pass

def onCustomEvent(event):
    pass

em = EventManager()

em.connect(PlayerDiesEvent, onPlayerDeath)
em.connect(CustomEvent, onCustomEvent)

# This notifies both functions, because `CustomEvent` is a `PlayerDiesEvent`
em.post(CustomEvent(...))

# This notifies only `onPlayerDeath`
em.post(PlayerDiesEvent(...))
```

**tld;dr:** Is there any C++ library that would allow me to more easily create a custom RTTI system that works with inheritance? If not, any ideas how I might implement this more easily and perhaps more generally (preferably in a way that is agnostic to my actual use case)?

Comment: What's wrong with the RTTI that's already in C++? How is it deficient for your needs?

Comment: @Nicol From the C++ perspective, Python types are just instances of PyObject (or boost::python::object), so the native RTTI isn't good. How could it work? C++'s RTTI only works with C++ types which are compile-time, as opposed to Python which is all run-time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with boost::python; it might have some feature that makes this easier. I just know of a custom RTTI system that works pretty well:

[Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28framework%29) has a [meta-object system](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/metaobjects.html), where reflection and a degree of dynamic behavior is added by having a [metaobject](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmetaobject.html) associated with each class that knows about that class's ancestors and methods. It's kind of like Python's class objects. A virtual method is used to get the metaobject from instances. A [custom compiler](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/moc.html) is used to generate these.

Qt's [Python](http://www.pyside.org/) [bindings](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download) then also create these metaobjects for Python classes, making them look almost identical to native QObjects classes as far as the meta-object system is concerned.

---

You need quite a bit less than Qt's general solution (you don't need info about methods/properties). So instead of a custom compiler, you could go with a C++-class definition macro that stores information about the class's ancestors. And then also update the information from the `__metaclass__` when a Python subclass is created, and query it when you're dispatching a message.

Comment: The Qt solution seems interesting. I'll study it and if I find it's too complex, maybe I'll make a striped down version of it for use in my code.